# Show calender between two dates

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have to create event tracking celender in which I have two dates, start date to end date.
I want to show calender from start date to end date in webpage.
i found this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/87835-event-tracking-calendar/
but its showing calender by month. and I want to create calender which can be from any date to end date.

Comment: Can anybody tell me that why they are giving down vote for this question? Although this is what I need. Thats why I am asking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution for this.

```
<section id="select-menu">
  <form method="post" action="index.php?action=GUI_calender">
    <select name="cycle" class="monthpicker" class="first-div-container">

    <?php

    $months = Array("Cycle 1", "Cycle 2", "Cycle 3", "Cycle 4", "Cycle 5", "Cycle 6", "Cycle 7", "Cycle 8", "Cycle 9", "Cycle 10", "Cycle 11");

    for ($x=1; $x<=count($months); $x++){
        echo "<option value=\"$x\"";
        if ($x == $cycle){
            echo " selected";
        }
        echo ">".$months[$x-1]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="pickerbutton" value="Go!">
</section>
    <?php
      echo "<table cellpadding=\"3\" ><tr>\n";
      foreach ($days as $day){
          echo "<th class=\"dayname\"><strong>$day</strong></th>\n";
      }
      ?>


<section id="header">
Total Days available in Cycle : <?php echo $number_of_days; ?>
</section>
<?php
      mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
      mysql_select_db("test");
    $dayArray = getdate($start);
    $number_of_days += ($dayArray['wday']+1);


    for ($count=0; $count<$number_of_days; $count++){
    $dayArray = getdate($start);  

      if (($count % 7) == 0){
          if (!in_array($dayArray['mon'],$months_in_cycle)){
              break;
          } else {
              echo "</tr><tr>\n";
          }
      }
      if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] || !in_array($dayArray['mon'],$months_in_cycle)){
          echo "<td> </td>\n";
      } else {

       $month = $dayArray['mon'];

    $total_calender = $obj_calender->total_calender($dayArray["mday"],$month,$current_year);

           echo "<td class=\"event\" valign=\"top\">".$dayArray["mday"]."<br/>"; 

          if ($total_calender > 0) {

                    $calender_detail = $obj_calender->get_calender_detail($dayArray["mday"],$month`enter code here`,$current_year);

                    foreach($calender_detail as $calender)
              {

             $event_title=$calender['mt_title'];
             $id=$calender['mt_id'];
                             $event_shortdesc=$calender['mt_desc'];
                             $eventtime=$calender['fmt_date'];
                             $eventduration=$calender['mt_duration'];
                             echo "<label class=\"eventcontent\"><a href='#' title=\"$event_title \n Event Desc : $event_shortdesc\n Event Time :  $eventtime  \n Event Duration : $eventduration\">#".$id."</a><lable><br>";
              } 
                   // mysql_free_result($chkEvent_res);
            } else {
                    $event_title = "";
            }


          echo "</td>\n";
          $start += ADAY;
      }
  }
  echo "</tr></table>";
  ?>

</form>

</div>
```